# Count Column if header is X (formula)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In sheet 1 I have:

```
(COL A)     | (COL B)
25/Aug/2016 | 30/Aug/2016
     X      |
            |      X
     X      |
     X      |      X
            |      X
            |
     X      |      X
```

In sheet 2, I want to count how many "X" does the sheet1 column A have, based on a vlookup by date.

I mean, in sheet 2, "if vlookup is 30 aug 2016, then count how many "X" are in corresponding column on sheet 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this a bit tricky. I sed this formula to solve your problem:

Assume that your table is like that:

[image]

Put this formula into cell **N1** and fill down:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($A$2),MATCH(A17,$A$1:$J$1,0),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW($A$13),MATCH(A17,$A$1:$J$1,0),4)),"=X")
```

And you can check [my example file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1V0ZhLS1SLXF2ZEU) as well.

Comment: I don't think you can use countifs like this, combining a row with a column

Comment: Perfect! However, I came up with something strange... I have the "X" on Sheet1, and the calculations have to be on Sheet2. And for some reason I don't know, it doesn't work that way...
Edit: I solved that! I just put "sheet1"&... before "address".. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet1!A:B,,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)),"X")
```

in Sheet2!B2, if the date to be matched is in Sheet2!A2.